# largest interval over which the general solution is defined

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

find largest interval over which the general solution is defined

$$\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{sin(x)}{cos(x)}y=\frac{1}{cos(x)}
\end{align}
$$

Integrating factor will be

$$\begin{align}\rightarrow I= e^{\int \frac{sin(x)}{cos(x)}dx}=e^{-ln|cos(x)|}=\frac{1}{cos(x)}\end{align}$$

Multiply I to each term of the equation

$$\begin{align}\rightarrow \frac{1}{cos(x)}\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{1}{cos(x)}\frac{sin(x)}{cos(x)}y=\frac{1}{cos(x)}\frac{1}{cos(x)}\end{align}$$

Integrate both sides:

$$\begin{align}\rightarrow \frac{d}{dx}(\frac{1}{cos(x)}y)=\int \frac{1}{cos^2(x)}\end{align}$$ (left side of the resulting equation is automatically the derivative of the integrating factor and y)

$$\begin{align}\rightarrow \frac{sin(x)}{cos^2(x)}y=tan(x)+C\end{align}$$

Explicit solution

$$\begin{align}\rightarrow y=\frac{cos^2(x)}{sin(x)}(tan(x)+C)\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}\rightarrow y=\frac{tan(x)}{sec(x)}+\frac{C}{sec(x)}\end{align}$$

if the steps were right this is so far I can go, having problems to find the largest interval from the solution and transient term, any help?

Comment: Recheck your fourth step the one after integrating on both sides

Comment: I believe its supposed to be $y=\frac{tanx}{secx} + \frac{C}{secx}$

Comment: corrected, still puzzled by the largest interval and finding transient term

Comment: both $secx$ and $tanx$ are undefined at integral multiples of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ so largest interval ought to be $\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [linear differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation). Therefore it is defined on the largest intervals for which the functions used in the differential equation are all defined.

Hence solutions are defined on intervals for which $\cos x$ doesn't vanish. If you want a solution defined at $0$, the interval is $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$

Answer (score 0):

For the transient, you are looking for any term that approaches 0 as x approaches infinity. In this problem, you would need to know if sec(x) goes to infinity if x approaches infinity. If it does, then both terms are transient terms